# Why using the composition operator allows you to avoid the need to explicitly refer the initial argument?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I can't seem to get my head around why the below code will not compile:

```
decode :: [Bit] -> String
decode xs = map  (chr . bin2int) . (chop8 xs)
```

But the below will:

```
decode :: [Bit] -> String
decode = map  (chr . bin2int) . chop8
```

When we give the 2nd function a list, it applies chop8 to it, then maps (chr . bin2int) to the elements in the list produced.

So why doesn't the 1st example do the same? Are we not effectively doing the same thing, but just giving chop8 the argument in the function definition?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the type and [implementation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#.) for `(.)`? Also ask ghci for `:t chop8` vs `:t chop8 []`

Comment: `(.)` composes two _functions_, `chop8` is a function, `chop8 xs` is not.

Comment: The correct version of your first snippet would be `decode xs = (map  (chr . bin2int) . chop8) xs`. (Actually it's more idiomatic to avoid the parentheses by using the `$` operator, but that's incidental.) Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `(.)` is key here.

To give a simpler example:

```
decode1, decode2 :: Int -> Char
decode1 x = chr . (abs x)
decode2 = chr . abs
```

Now, the definition of `(.)` is `f . g = \a -> f (g a)`, so we can use that in both of our definitions:

```
decode1 x = \a -> chr (abs x a)
decode2 = \x -> chr (abs x)
```

We can further simplify this, by moving the lambda parameters into the pattern match:

```
decode1 x a = chr (abs x a)
decode2 x = chr (abs x)
```

Obviously `decode2` is the right funtion; `decode1` doesn't even typecheck. `abs` only takes one argument, but `decode1` calls it with 2! Furthermore, `decode1` has an extra parameter, `a`, which we don't want.

Comment: Thanks for that, I understand now! All in all, ( . ) can only be applied to a function, not the result of one!

Comment: Shouldn't `decode1` be `(ord . abs) x`, not `ord . (abs x)`?

Comment: @bradrn, `ord . (abs x)` is the equivalent of `map  (chr . bin2int) . (chop8 xs)` in the original question. Neither are valid expressions.

Comment: @IzaakWeiss That's what I'm saying! Actually, I've just realised that IzaakWeiss _did_ say that `decode1` 'doesn't even typecheck'; I missed that when I wrote my comment.

Answer (score 4):

The second version, using what is called point-free style, does not require the "xs" parameter because the expression `map  (chr . bin2int) . chop8` already produces a function of type `[Bit] -> String` - so all you have is to set `decode =` to the expression's value.

With the first version, you are explicitly passing the `xs` argument, so the expression to the right side of `=` should be of type `Int`. Since you are explicitly applying chop8 to xs, the result is a concrete list, not a function.

One solution is to explicitly apply map to the result of chop8:

```hs
decode xs = map  (chr . bin2int) $ (chop8 xs)
```

Note the replacement of `.` with `$` - "apply function to parameter" instead of "compose function with another function"

Comment: Thanks for your help :) The composition operator can only be applied to functions, not lists!?

Comment: Yes - the closest thing for lists would be to concatenate them (both composition and concatenation obey identity and associative laws), but that isn't relevant to this case.